# Ball splitting and merging

Tags: visual-c++, graphics, 3d

I am making a simple OpenGl program to draw some balls that split up when they collide to the wall with their radius `halved` and merge when two balls collide by `adding` up their radius...
I have got my functions working properly but the problem is that I can not add both splitting and merging in the same program.
Reason: A ball splits at a instant by colliding to the wall and at the same instant both balls are still in contact so `act_On_Collision()` merges the two ball again.
Thus the balls never break or merge and also when all the balls are initialised from the same points they all get merged but nothing appears on the screan. download source code [here](http://www.4shared.com/zip/-gj9uoGS/FunBall.html)

SO any help/idea about this is welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some hysteresis in the split/merge conditional. I.e. when a split happens the two balls should first move a certain distance from each other, before their merge logic gets enabled.

Or you make use of the velocity vector, i.e. only balls which velocity further reduces their distance merge. After the split their motion vectors should point apart.

Comment: That's what I thought at first. 


 
To use some distance logic or time logic but can you give me a detailed algo for it.

Answer (score 1):

Two balls will never join when it is in contact with wall. So you can use that condition. When two balls are in contact and not in contact with wall they will join.